# Linearization/Directional Derivative relationship?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, linearization

I'm a little confused by the following question:

> You know that a function f(x, y, z) satisfies f(0, 0, 0) = 33 and
>   $D_{<1,1,1>/
> √
> 3}$
>   f(0, 0, 0) = 4/√3 and $D_{<1,1,0>/
> √2}$
>   f(0, 0, 0) = 7/√2 and
>   $D_{<1,2,2>/3}$f(0, 0, 0) = 12. Estimate f(0.01, −0.001, 0.1) using linearization.

So my thought process is that we can make up some phony equation that satisfies the first f(0,0,0), say x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup> + 33 = f(x,y,z). However, after this I am awfully stuck: how do we use directional derivatives to help with linearization?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try $f(x) = a + b^T x$ for suitable $a,b$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 1D case of approximation:
$$
g(x_0)\approx g(0)+g'(0)x_0
$$
All you need to approximate $g(x_0)$ is knowing $g(0)$, $g'(0)$ and $x_0$. You don't need to know the "expression" of $g$.

The 3D case is similar:
$$
f(a)\approx f(0)+f_x(0)a_1+f_y(0)a_2+f_z(0)a_3
$$
where $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$. Now you see that you need to find $f_x(0), f_y(0), f_z(0)$. How?

Note that you have the assumptions for three [directional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative). On the other hand, 
$$
D_vf(0)=\nabla f(0)\cdot v
$$ 
which give you a hint that you would need to solve a linear equation so that you can find
$$
\nabla f(0)=(f_x(0),f_y(0),f_z(0))
$$